# CSS @keyframes wont stay

Tags: html, css

Using the @keyframes, I am trying to get the boxes to animate to 200px and stay while the user is hovered. But it seems that it only grows it to the 200px then reset. I reken that this is because it only animates it when activated not while it is being hovered on.

```css
#box1,
#box2,
#box3,
#box4 {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-bottom: 2px red solid;
  float: left;
}
#box1 {
  background-color: #6bff05;
}
#box2 {
  background-color: #00ffff;
}
#box3 {
  background-color: #e000f1;
}
#box4 {
  background-color: #ff8c00;
}
#box5 {
  height: 100px;
  width: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-bottom: 2px red solid;
  float: left;
  background-color: #f4ff00;
}
#box1:hover,
#box2:hover,
#box3:hover,
#box4:hover {
  -webkit-animation-name: boxGrow;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
}
@-webkit-keyframes boxGrow {
  from {
    width: 100px;
  }
  to {
    width: 200px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="box1" class="animated"><a href="#">Home</a>
  </div>
  <div id="box2"><a href="#">about</a>
  </div>
  <div id="box3"><a href="#">Information</a>
  </div>
  <div id="box4"><a href="#">contact me</a>
  </div>
  <div id="box5"><a href="#">...</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add `animation-fill-mode: forwards` to your `:hover` rules

```
#box1:hover,
#box2:hover,
#box3:hover,
#box4:hover {
    -webkit-animation-name: boxGrow;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

Also, you could achieve the same thing just using transitions:

```
#box1,
#box2,
#box3,
#box4 {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-bottom: 2px red solid;
  float: left;
  transition: width 1s ease;
}

#box1:hover,
#box2:hover,
#box3:hover,
#box4:hover {
    width: 200px
}
```

Also, please add the same animation without vendor prefixes... just to make sure it will work in other browsers too :-)